# Sorting float values within Element UI Table-Columns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, element-ui

Hi i am creating a table using Element UI and one of the columns has floats as values, however when I make the column sortable it does not sort it correctly.

Here is my column's code

```html
<el-table-column
  label="Total Opportunity"
  prop="blood_utilization_opportunity"
  sortable
>
  <template slot-scope="slotData">
     <span>{{slotData.row.blood_utilization_opportunity}}</span>
  </template>
</el-table-column>
```

I am looking at the Element UI Table-column Attributes, but I am not sure which one to use to make the column correctly sort through floats...

Comment: Please revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. A list of words isn't helpful.

Comment: What numbers does it fail to sort correctly?

Comment: I have number ranging from 0.0 to 100.0 the way it sorts it, it goes through all the floats that start with 1s and then goes to 2s. so a value of 10.5 is being places before a value of 2.3

Comment: [_"To apply your own sorting rules, use `sort-method` or `sort-by`"_](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/table#sorting)... ah, good old Element UI, the worst documented Vue component library. I assume you'd need to use one of these cryptic props. How you use them exactly is a mystery

Comment: yeah exactly, I am not sure how to use those attributes, there is not many docs on how to use them properly.

Comment: It only does this with string representations of the floats, it sorts actual floats ok.  It might be easier to format the data properly in a computed than to interpret the Element docs

Answer (score 0):

The type of your data is String, not Number.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is a famous "sort" bug in javascript with the classic `sort` function.

It sort the numbers by digit instead of the whole number.

Example :

```js
const arr = [1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.1, 5.6, 11.1, 12.0, 21.0].sort()
console.log(arr)
```

As seen in the [documentation](https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/table.html#sorting)

> To apply your own sorting rules, use `sort-method` or `sort-by`

So the best thing to do is to define your own sort method in the methods and pass it to the component

### Method

```js
methods: {
   sortListMethod(a, b){
      return a - b
   }
}
```

### Template

```js
<el-table-column
  label="Total Opportunity"
  prop="blood_utilization_opportunity"*
  sort-method="sortListMethod"
  sortable
> ... </el-table-column>
```